# count with same combination in a given date range

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I have 2 table Offense table and User_jobs table

offense table:

```
crime_id |crime_type |casenumber| date       |
---------+-----------+----------+------------+
1        | 3         |1         |2011        |
2        | 3         |1         |2010        |
1        | 3         |2         |2012        |
12       | AA        |2         |2011        |
```

user_jobs table:

```
casenumber |disposal_status |
-----------+----------------+
1          | yes            |
1          | yes            |
2          | no             |
2          | no             |
```

what i want is to count the number of rows with the same combination but in a giver date range say crime_id=1 and crime_type= 3 from 2010 - 2012 but these must have a disposal status of yes in the user_jobs table

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT crime_id,crime_type,count(*) as numberOfRows
FROM offense_table o
INNER JOIN users_table u
      ON o.casenumber=u.casenumber
WHERE u.disposal_status='yes' 
      AND `date` BETWEEN 2010 AND 2012
GROUP BY crime_id,crime_type
```

OUTPIT

```
crime_id |crime_type |numberOfRows
---------+-----------+----------+
1        | 3         |1         |
2        | 3         |1         |
```

Comment: thanx. now i want to use timestamp. so i want to select say between 2014-04-01 10:37:58 and 2014-04-01 14:37:58